# Url rewrite for a domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need it so when i go to `mydomainname.com/page/week1` it will show `mydomainname.com/page.php?month=week1`. Will my code do that ?

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomianname.com$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomianname.com$
rewriterule ^mydomianname\.com/page/?([-A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ "http\:\/\/mydomianname\.com\/page\.php?month=$1" [L]
```

When I go to `mydomainame.com/page/week1` I get

> the requested URL /page/week1 was not found on this server.

my current http access

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.fetustobaby.com$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fetustobaby.com$
rewriterule ^fetustobaby\.com\/page\/([-A-Za-z0-9]*)\/?$ page.php?month=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some issues like RewriteRule only matches URL and host name matching is not part of RewriteRule. Here is the fixed code that you can use in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomianname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ /page.php?month=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: i get a Internal Server Error

Comment: Try it now. Sorry I typed dot instead of a comma before QSA :(

Comment: i get Not Found
The requested URL /page/month1 was not found on this server.

Comment: Well if you type this URL in browser: `/page.php?month=month1` does it display the correct page content?

Comment: Nope does not show the correct info. My site is http://fetustobaby.com/ and has you can see we grab the number from the url like so http://fetustobaby.com/page.php?Month=1   but it looks ugly and is not very good for seo so wanted to try and make it shorter and nicer...

Comment: Make sure mod_rewrite and .htaccess is enabled and above code is placed in `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file.

Comment: Also post your most current .htaccess in your question.

Comment: posted. it in my first post

Comment: That is not what I suggested in my answer.